# having different cell types (textboxes, dropdownlists, checkboxes, radiobuttons) in a DataGridView according to data filled

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have miscellaneous data in a table consisting of string, bool and integer.

I am making a user editable datagridview, but i want where there is bool data type, there should be radio buttons, where data type is string there should be text boxes and so on....

TIA

Comment: Try using Infragistics or Telerik Winforms controls, they have all this functionality I suppose..

Comment: could not find much on it....do you have a link to a nice tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved Finally!! Phew!

I am able to change the cell type as follows.

I have created cells for different datatypes....like for e.g. boolean data

```
DataGridViewComboBoxCell cb_cell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
cb_cell.Items.Add((object)"true");
cb_cell.Items.Add((object)"false");
```

and when i check the datatype i add

```
if (dsData.Tables[0].Rows[i]["DataType"].ToString().ToLower().Contains("bool"))
{
    gvData.Rows[i].Cells[2] = cb_cell;
    gvData.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = dsData.Tables[0].Rows[i]["DataValue"];
}
```

Where ds is the DataSet returned from my SQL query